# How to obtain the same output from sencha app watch and sencha app build?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6

When I use sencha app watch on a new app created by sencha cmd, I obtain, inspecting with browser tools, a readable app.js. Doing the same using sencha app build, the app.js file is minified and hard to debug.

How can I obtain the same result of sencha app watch from sencha app build?

Answer (score 0):

Executes the build process for an application in different environment by adding extra parameter at end..

```
sencha app build [production|testing|native|package]
```

For you sencha app build testing will not create minified  JS files..

By default it take production environment..That's why you getting minified  JS files

Comment: Hi Abhijit, thanks for your answer. 
With "sencha app build testing" I obtain the same result as using production option. Do you know if there's some options in sencha config files that can change the build behavior?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Browser console always show minified js file.